# Error "Cannot Resolve Symbol R "

Tags: java, android, cannot-find-symbol

My Android Studio is keep on giving error **Cannot Resolve Symbol R**. It is a file in Android Directory named as **R.java**. I Have this file safely in the Directory. But still, it is Showing Error. After Searching for this error on internet, People Suggest me to do Rebuild/Clean/Gradle Project Sync/Restart Android Studio and other methods. I Did Everything. But still, Problem is there! What To Do??

Comment: Go to terminal. Type `gradlew clean build`. Do you get any errors? Building from the terminal can sometimes show errors that aren't shown by the UI.

Comment: It's an error that I see from time to time but after a build it goes away. Does you project build successfully?

Comment: @MichaelDodd I Did it 2-3 Times.. But Still.. No Change

Comment: @mTak But In my Case, the error is showing while building. And Yes, My Project was successfully Build about 40-50 times before. But Suddenly, This Error Comes.

Comment: Can u post your code where's error is showing.

Comment: Try something that worked for me once: Close the project and in the popupwindow select Import Project(Gradle, Eclipse,..)

Comment: If you just upgrade AndroidStudio or gradle. You maybe need to delete the cache repository of gradle (on linux ~/.gradle/*), not only in your app directory. I suggest you to rebuild your app on other computer. That way, you will know if it's your code who has a problem or if it's a configuration issue on your computer.

Comment: @Raj Thanks for asking for Code. But Actually, My Code Works Fine before One Day. But when Next day I start Android Studio, It Shows same error on every activity which have something like "R.id" or "R.Layout" with red Text. I have about 10 Activities. Also, I have Build it and install it on my phone. So, There's No chance that code is wrong. There's something wrong with software I think..

Comment: @MichaelDodd In Build Log, It is Showing, "Failed Linking File Resources" for R.java

Comment: @AyushSingh a screenshot always helps, not saying there is anything wrong with the code. Just post a screen shot from one of the activities where you are getting the error.  One possible solution is to invalidate cache and restart (did you already do that?)

Comment: Thanks to Everyone for Answering. Actually, There was something wrong with my Drawable Directory. Because when I Update it with the same files of my old projects. It Builds Successfully! and Everything started Working fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sometimes happens if there's an error in one or more resource files (xml). Check your layout files and files in the values folder for errors. Check the AndroidManifest file as well.

Comment: Thanks! Your Answer helps me. Actually, There was something wrong with my Drawable Directory. Because when I Update it with the same files of my old projects. It Builds Successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ; therefore, there are some things that you can try to solve your issues.

- Try to Sync your project: Go to File, Click on Sync Project with
  Gradles File
- Try to Invalidate the Cache: Go to File, Click on Invalidate Caches /
  Restart...

Let me know if this works for you in case we need to try something else.